# html form with Php code not executing

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP. I have this html file with php in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Php torturail 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>php ahead:</p>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    printf('User Name: %s', $_POST['name']);
        }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <p>name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>pass:</p>
    <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <p>massage:</p>
    <textarea name="area"></textarea>
    <p>accept:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb" value="on">
    <p>lucky number:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="option1">1
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="option2">2
    <p>button:</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open it on on a browser and click submit, the form's fileds are empty again but nothing is printed.

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You need a PHP file with HTML in it :-) Rename to `.php`  assuming that you have a webserver with PHP installed.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:
1-you must save your file as .php file.
2-fill action in your form tag

```
<form method="post" action="where.php">
```

Comment: A blank `action` will make it post to itself.

Comment: the file is .php, I also tried to put the file's name in action but it still doesn't work /: